# Keyboard not popping up in phone authentication using firebase in android studio after I click on autofill from message in my honor phone

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement phone authentication in android using firebase. Here, when I try to login by other person mobile number then in editText when I tap then it shows "Autofill Code from Messages". If I click autofill then it stops showing the keyboard and after my continuous tap on that editText even doesn't bring keyboard up to enter. Please help. Here is the code associated :

```
public class otpVerification extends AppCompatActivity {

private String mVerificationId;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView resend;
private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressBar = (findViewById(R.id.progressbar));
    editText = (findViewById(R.id.editTextCode));
    resend = findViewById(R.id.resend);

    final String mobile = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");

    sendVerificationCode(mobile);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code = editText.getText().toString();
            if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                editText.setEnabled(true);
                editText.setError("Enter code manually");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            } else if (code.replace(" ", "").length() != 6) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(otpVerification.this, "Enter correct OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //verifying the code
                verifyVerificationCode(code);
            }
        }
    });

    resend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendVerificationCode(mobile);
        }
    });
}

private void verifyVerificationCode(String otp) {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, otp);
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(otpVerification.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //verification successful we will start the profile activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(otpVerification.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(otpVerification.this, "Verification failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            resend.setText("" + l / 1000);
            resend.setEnabled(false);
            editText.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            resend.setText(" Resend");
            resend.setEnabled(true);
            editText.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.start();

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+91" + mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallbacks);
}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        mVerificationId = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            editText.setText(code);
            verifyVerificationCode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(otpVerification.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about your case but once I faced that same thing and that was because I was showing the edited text in a bottom sheet, that was somehow restricting the Keyboard to popup.

Comment: Hi Waqas, I have put my editText slightly up only so that keyboard can popup easily. Actually, in various devices it is working properly but in honor mobiles it is creating problems. Please help if you know or if I am writing something wrong in code

Comment: is there any thing like we can disable that "autofill code from message option" in any UI?